# media queries and to adapt the ready made site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am now having to *adjust* my current site to fit it into a smaller desktop screen size. It is viewable on all screens, only with smaller ones like 14", it creates a scrollbar on the left and is not required.

They ask me to scale down everything possible to fit the site into 14" but still to be viewable like when it appears with larger screen sizes. Someone could help me deal with this ? And No, iphone screen is not an option, only different desktop screens, especially the small ones.

Could you advise what I should change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- Alter your current stylesheet so that it works on smaller devices (14" isn't *that* small, so this might be a good option). This would be a simple way to get rid of the scrollbar.
- Write a separate stylesheet that applies only to certain devices, and use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to target the devices you want (for example using the `min-width`, `max-width` expressions). This means you can tweak the stylesheet for smaller devices as much as you like and not risk breaking the page for larger devices.

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is a good example of a website who's stylesheet changes as you resize the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already got stylesheets and a website written, it's harder to do from scratch.

But you can add

```
@media screen and (min-width: ###px) and (max-width: ###px) {
    .sample { /*stuff here */ }
    body { /* stuff here */ }
}
```

to the bottom of your style sheet.

You can change the ### above to be the min and max widths you need. So you can have like

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
```

and

```
@media screen and (min-width: 479px) and (max-width: 767px) {
```

etc. for all the sizes you need.